# How to loading stickers into WhatsApp using ContentProvider

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, android-contentprovider, whatsapp-stickers

I have a list of sticker URLs that I obtained from Firebase, and I would like to load these stickers into WhatsApp using a ContentProvider. Currently, the app uses the StickerContentProvider class provided in the official WhatsApp stickers repository on GitHub, which loads stickers from the app's assets folder. However, I need to modify this class to meet my requirements.

The StickerContentProvider class from the WhatsApp stickers repository can be found here: [https://github.com/WhatsApp/stickers/blob/main/Android/app/src/main/java/com/example/samplestickerapp/StickerContentProvider.java]

My objective is to customize this class to fetch stickers from Firebase Storage instead of the assets folder. The list of sticker URLs will be retrieved from Firebase.

I would greatly appreciate it if someone could help me modify the StickerContentProvider class to achieve this requirement.

Modify the logic to downlaod the stickers from Firebase Storage using the provided sticker URLs. This may involve replacing the existing code that loads stickers from the assets folder.

Ensure that the downloaded stickers from Firebase Storage are processed correctly and displayed in the app's sticker interface.

I have attempted to make these modifications myself, but due to the complexity of the code and my limited experience with Firebase integration, I am facing difficulties.

Any assistance or guidance in customizing the StickerContentProvider class to fetch stickers from Firebase Storage would be highly appreciated.

Thank you for your time and assistance.

Change this class accourding to requirements:

```
public class StickerContentProvider extends ContentProvider {

    /**
     * Do not change the strings listed below, as these are used by WhatsApp. And changing these will break the interface between sticker app and WhatsApp.
     */
    public static final String STICKER_PACK_IDENTIFIER_IN_QUERY = "sticker_pack_identifier";
    public static final String STICKER_PACK_NAME_IN_QUERY = "sticker_pack_name";
    public static final String STICKER_PACK_PUBLISHER_IN_QUERY = "sticker_pack_publisher";
    public static final String STICKER_PACK_ICON_IN_QUERY = "sticker_pack_icon";
    public static final String ANDROID_APP_DOWNLOAD_LINK_IN_QUERY = "android_play_store_link";
    public static final String IOS_APP_DOWNLOAD_LINK_IN_QUERY = "ios_app_download_link";
    public static final String PUBLISHER_EMAIL = "sticker_pack_publisher_email";
    public static final String PUBLISHER_WEBSITE = "sticker_pack_publisher_website";
    public static final String PRIVACY_POLICY_WEBSITE = "sticker_pack_privacy_policy_website";
    public static final String LICENSE_AGREENMENT_WEBSITE = "sticker_pack_license_agreement_website";
    public static final String IMAGE_DATA_VERSION = "image_data_version";
    public static final String AVOID_CACHE = "whatsapp_will_not_cache_stickers";
    public static final String ANIMATED_STICKER_PACK = "animated_sticker_pack";

    public static final String STICKER_FILE_NAME_IN_QUERY = "sticker_file_name";
    public static final String STICKER_FILE_EMOJI_IN_QUERY = "sticker_emoji";
    private static final String CONTENT_FILE_NAME = "contents.json";

    public static final Uri AUTHORITY_URI = new Uri.Builder().scheme(ContentResolver.SCHEME_CONTENT).authority(BuildConfig.CONTENT_PROVIDER_AUTHORITY).appendPath(StickerContentProvider.METADATA).build();

    /**
     * Do not change the values in the UriMatcher because otherwise, WhatsApp will not be able to fetch the stickers from the ContentProvider.
     */
    private static final UriMatcher MATCHER = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);
    private static final String METADATA = "metadata";
    private static final int METADATA_CODE = 1;

    private static final int METADATA_CODE_FOR_SINGLE_PACK = 2;

    static final String STICKERS = "stickers";
    private static final int STICKERS_CODE = 3;

    static final String STICKERS_ASSET = "stickers_asset";
    private static final int STICKERS_ASSET_CODE = 4;

    private static final int STICKER_PACK_TRAY_ICON_CODE = 5;

    private List<StickerPack> stickerPackList;

    @Override
    public boolean onCreate() {
        final String authority = BuildConfig.CONTENT_PROVIDER_AUTHORITY;
        if (!authority.startsWith(Objects.requireNonNull(getContext()).getPackageName())) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("your authority (" + authority + ") for the content provider should start with your package name: " + getContext().getPackageName());
        }

        //the call to get the metadata for the sticker packs.
        MATCHER.addURI(authority, METADATA, METADATA_CODE);

        //the call to get the metadata for single sticker pack. * represent the identifier
        MATCHER.addURI(authority, METADATA + "/*", METADATA_CODE_FOR_SINGLE_PACK);

        //gets the list of stickers for a sticker pack, * respresent the identifier.
        MATCHER.addURI(authority, STICKERS + "/*", STICKERS_CODE);

        for (StickerPack stickerPack : getStickerPackList()) {
            MATCHER.addURI(authority, STICKERS_ASSET + "/" + stickerPack.identifier + "/" + stickerPack.trayImageFile, STICKER_PACK_TRAY_ICON_CODE);
            for (Sticker sticker : stickerPack.getStickers()) {
                MATCHER.addURI(authority, STICKERS_ASSET + "/" + stickerPack.identifier + "/" + sticker.imageFileName, STICKERS_ASSET_CODE);
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public Cursor query(@NonNull Uri uri, @Nullable String[] projection, String selection,
                        String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {
        final int code = MATCHER.match(uri);
        if (code == METADATA_CODE) {
            return getPackForAllStickerPacks(uri);
        } else if (code == METADATA_CODE_FOR_SINGLE_PACK) {
            return getCursorForSingleStickerPack(uri);
        } else if (code == STICKERS_CODE) {
            return getStickersForAStickerPack(uri);
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URI: " + uri);
        }
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public AssetFileDescriptor openAssetFile(@NonNull Uri uri, @NonNull String mode) {
        final int matchCode = MATCHER.match(uri);
        if (matchCode == STICKERS_ASSET_CODE || matchCode == STICKER_PACK_TRAY_ICON_CODE) {
            return getImageAsset(uri);
        }
        return null;
    }


    @Override
    public String getType(@NonNull Uri uri) {
        final int matchCode = MATCHER.match(uri);
        switch (matchCode) {
            case METADATA_CODE:
                return "vnd.android.cursor.dir/vnd." + BuildConfig.CONTENT_PROVIDER_AUTHORITY + "." + METADATA;
            case METADATA_CODE_FOR_SINGLE_PACK:
                return "vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd." + BuildConfig.CONTENT_PROVIDER_AUTHORITY + "." + METADATA;
            case STICKERS_CODE:
                return "vnd.android.cursor.dir/vnd." + BuildConfig.CONTENT_PROVIDER_AUTHORITY + "." + STICKERS;
            case STICKERS_ASSET_CODE:
                return "image/webp";
            case STICKER_PACK_TRAY_ICON_CODE:
                return "image/png";
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URI: " + uri);
        }
    }

    private synchronized void readContentFile(@NonNull Context context) {
        try (InputStream contentsInputStream = context.getAssets().open(CONTENT_FILE_NAME)) {
            stickerPackList = ContentFileParser.parseStickerPacks(contentsInputStream);
        } catch (IOException | IllegalStateException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(CONTENT_FILE_NAME + " file has some issues: " + e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }

    private List<StickerPack> getStickerPackList() {
        if (stickerPackList == null) {
            readContentFile(Objects.requireNonNull(getContext()));
        }
        return stickerPackList;
    }

    private Cursor getPackForAllStickerPacks(@NonNull Uri uri) {
        return getStickerPackInfo(uri, getStickerPackList());
    }

    private Cursor getCursorForSingleStickerPack(@NonNull Uri uri) {
        final String identifier = uri.getLastPathSegment();
        for (StickerPack stickerPack : getStickerPackList()) {
            if (identifier.equals(stickerPack.identifier)) {
                return getStickerPackInfo(uri, Collections.singletonList(stickerPack));
            }
        }

        return getStickerPackInfo(uri, new ArrayList<>());
    }

    @NonNull
    private Cursor getStickerPackInfo(@NonNull Uri uri, @NonNull List<StickerPack> stickerPackList) {
        MatrixCursor cursor = new MatrixCursor(
                new String[]{
                        STICKER_PACK_IDENTIFIER_IN_QUERY,
                        STICKER_PACK_NAME_IN_QUERY,
                        STICKER_PACK_PUBLISHER_IN_QUERY,
                        STICKER_PACK_ICON_IN_QUERY,
                        ANDROID_APP_DOWNLOAD_LINK_IN_QUERY,
                        IOS_APP_DOWNLOAD_LINK_IN_QUERY,
                        PUBLISHER_EMAIL,
                        PUBLISHER_WEBSITE,
                        PRIVACY_POLICY_WEBSITE,
                        LICENSE_AGREENMENT_WEBSITE,
                        IMAGE_DATA_VERSION,
                        AVOID_CACHE,
                        ANIMATED_STICKER_PACK,
                });
        for (StickerPack stickerPack : stickerPackList) {
            MatrixCursor.RowBuilder builder = cursor.newRow();
            builder.add(stickerPack.identifier);
            builder.add(stickerPack.name);
            builder.add(stickerPack.publisher);
            builder.add(stickerPack.trayImageFile);
            builder.add(stickerPack.androidPlayStoreLink);
            builder.add(stickerPack.iosAppStoreLink);
            builder.add(stickerPack.publisherEmail);
            builder.add(stickerPack.publisherWebsite);
            builder.add(stickerPack.privacyPolicyWebsite);
            builder.add(stickerPack.licenseAgreementWebsite);
            builder.add(stickerPack.imageDataVersion);
            builder.add(stickerPack.avoidCache ? 1 : 0);
            builder.add(stickerPack.animatedStickerPack ? 1 : 0);
        }
        cursor.setNotificationUri(Objects.requireNonNull(getContext()).getContentResolver(), uri);
        return cursor;
    }

    @NonNull
    private Cursor getStickersForAStickerPack(@NonNull Uri uri) {
        final String identifier = uri.getLastPathSegment();
        MatrixCursor cursor = new MatrixCursor(new String[]{STICKER_FILE_NAME_IN_QUERY, STICKER_FILE_EMOJI_IN_QUERY});
        for (StickerPack stickerPack : getStickerPackList()) {
            if (identifier.equals(stickerPack.identifier)) {
                for (Sticker sticker : stickerPack.getStickers()) {
                    cursor.addRow(new Object[]{sticker.imageFileName, TextUtils.join(",", sticker.emojis)});
                }
            }
        }
        cursor.setNotificationUri(Objects.requireNonNull(getContext()).getContentResolver(), uri);
        return cursor;
    }

    private AssetFileDescriptor getImageAsset(Uri uri) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        AssetManager am = Objects.requireNonNull(getContext()).getAssets();
        final List<String> pathSegments = uri.getPathSegments();
        if (pathSegments.size() != 3) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("path segments should be 3, uri is: " + uri);
        }
        String fileName = pathSegments.get(pathSegments.size() - 1);
        final String identifier = pathSegments.get(pathSegments.size() - 2);
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(identifier)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("identifier is empty, uri: " + uri);
        }
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(fileName)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("file name is empty, uri: " + uri);
        }
        //making sure the file that is trying to be fetched is in the list of stickers.
        for (StickerPack stickerPack : getStickerPackList()) {
            if (identifier.equals(stickerPack.identifier)) {
                if (fileName.equals(stickerPack.trayImageFile)) {
                    return fetchFile(uri, am, fileName, identifier);
                } else {
                    for (Sticker sticker : stickerPack.getStickers()) {
                        if (fileName.equals(sticker.imageFileName)) {
                            return fetchFile(uri, am, fileName, identifier);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    private AssetFileDescriptor fetchFile(@NonNull Uri uri, @NonNull AssetManager am, @NonNull String fileName, @NonNull String identifier) {
        try {
            return am.openFd(identifier + "/" + fileName);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(Objects.requireNonNull(getContext()).getPackageName(), "IOException when getting asset file, uri:" + uri, e);
            return null;
        }
    }


    @Override
    public int delete(@NonNull Uri uri, @Nullable String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported");
    }

    @Override
    public Uri insert(@NonNull Uri uri, ContentValues values) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported");
    }

    @Override
    public int update(@NonNull Uri uri, ContentValues values, String selection,
                      String[] selectionArgs) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported");
    }
}
```

Comment: You'll have to download the stickers locally, say somewhere in the `context.filesDir`, build a `StickerPack` object with those URI paths & use them in the `ContentProvider`.